# Definition of a contingent claim X

Tags: finance

I try to understand what a T-claim is and I am asking for an intuitive explanation?

For instance. Let’s say I buy a zero coupon bond that will pay me 1 in two years. In terms of expressing as a T-claim Where T=2: how wil X then look like? Maybe X=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the claim payoff at time 2 is X=1

Comment: Hi Peter, it seems you have multiple accounts. You can merge them [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).